# телеграмм бот bot.polling()

Tags: парсер, telegram-bot, python-3.9

```
2022-04-07 17:38:23,815 (__init__.py:663 MainThread) INFO - TeleBot: "Started polling."
2022-04-07 17:38:23,816 (util.py:84 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Received task"
2022-04-07 17:38:23,816 (apihelper.py:88 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=get url=https://api.telegram.org/bot5186758570:{TOKEN}/getUpdates params={'offset': 1, 'timeout': 20, 'long_polling_timeout': 20} files=None"
2022-04-07 17:38:44,020 (apihelper.py:156 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":[]}''"
2022-04-07 17:38:44,021 (__init__.py:414 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Received 0 new updates"
2022-04-07 17:38:44,021 (util.py:88 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Task complete"
2022-04-07 17:38:44,021 (util.py:84 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Received task"
2022-04-07 17:38:44,021 (apihelper.py:88 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=get url=https://api.telegram.org/bot5186758570:{TOKEN}/getUpdates params={'offset': 1, 'timeout': 20, 'long_polling_timeout': 20} files=None"
2022-04-07 17:39:04,070 (apihelper.py:156 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":[]}''"
```

Выходит вот такая вот ошибка при запуске на хостинге телеграмм бота, я использовал мультипоточность и логирование. Помогите решить эту ошибку пожалуйста. если я запускаю бота локально, то все работает. Но я использую ОС Windows, а на хостинге используется Linux. Может это как-нибудь повлиять на мой код?

Comment: отформатируйте свой вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: а ошибка где, в каком месте?

Comment: я думаю мне нужно изменить именно bot.polling()

Comment: здесь нет ни одной ошибки. то, что вы привели в вопросе - информационные и отладочные сообщения.